# How do I translate Quasar component?

Tags: vue.js, internationalization, quasar-framework

I have a Vue/Quasar application in which I use [i18n](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/) but now I'm facing a problem: table footer doesn't get translated. In the table headers, for example, I do something like this to translate column names:

```
{
  align: 'left',
  field: (val) => val,
  label: this.$t('locale.column'),
  name: 'column',
  required: true,
  sortable: true,
},
```

where $t is 18n function, locale is my component and the column is actually's column's name. I don't have direct access to the footer of the table (where the pagination an the total number of the elements are) and it doesn't get translated. I also use Quasar language packs, quasar.js goes like this:

```
import en from 'quasar/lang/en-us.js'
/*
  import other languages
*/
import {
  state,
} from '@state/modules/i18n';

const locale = state.locale;
const langDictionary = {
  // all the imported langs go here
};

Vue.use(Quasar, {
  config: {},
  components: { /* not needed if importStrategy is not 'manual' */ },
  directives: { /* not needed if importStrategy is not 'manual' */ },
  plugins: {
    Cookies,
    Dialog,
    Loading,
    Notify,
  },
  lang: langDictionary[locale]
});

export {langDictionary};
```

Answer (score 1):

You are probably setting the language at startup correctly as `lang: langDictionary[locale]`. If you change the language state in your app later, you need to also inform Quasar if you want Quasar components and plugins to get correctly translated. See the docs, [Change Quasar Language Pack at Runtime](https://quasar.dev/options/quasar-language-packs#Change-Quasar-Language-Pack-at-Runtime) for how to achieve that, the docs about language pack also includes tips for dynamically loading the language pack.

You didn't specify how you change the language in your app, so I can't give an example built upon that.